# А почему текстовый редактор форума такой малофункциональный?

Tags: поддержка, метки, страница-учётной-записи, форматирование, редактор

Попробуйте к примеру превратить часть вашего сообщения вот в такой маркерный список

- Пункт
- Пункт
- Пункт

только если с бубном рядом кто-то пляшет...

... а метки как размещать? Пробел завершает создание метки, а как из двух слов? Нижнее подчёркивание рисовать?!

А как увидеть мои вопросы? Где ссылка на те вопросы, которые я опубликовал?

Comment: Вряд ли вопрос принадлежит мете. Господин ТС читайте справку.

Comment: С подключением! В вебе вообще не бывает хороших текстовых редакторов. Там обычно какое-нибудь костыльное встроенное текстовое окно с парой кривых js скриптов. Просто редактируйте любой текст в vim или emacs и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @igumnov: вот вам индусский онлайн-Vi. http://www.compileonline.com/online_vi_editor.php

Comment: В одном вопросе - куча вопросов. А ответ один: [Справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 9):

Используется популярная система разметки Markdown. Она довольно проста в освоении, и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) хорошая справка, которая, кстати, доступна из окна редактирования.

Answer (score 4):

> как увидеть мои вопросы? Где ссылка на те вопросы, которые я опубликовал?

ссылка на [ваш профиль](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/183789) — непосредственно под вашим «ником» и посередине чёрной строки вверху страницы (в том месте, где отображается аватар, репутация и полученные знаки).

на странице с профилем можно обнаружить много полезной информации. в частности — ссылки на [все заданные вами вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/183789/?tab=questions).

Answer (score 4):

Про markdown вам уже ответили, добавлю что прямо в окне редактора есть кнопка с вопросительным знаком. За ней скрывается справка по редактору. (Неожиданный ход разработчиков:) )

Почти всё, что нужно для вопросов и ответов о программировании, есть в Markdown (кроме таблиц*, эх). Какие-то сложные стили и не нужны, я считаю. Всё-таки мы не не блогосервис.

Про метки: движок сайта так устроен, что в названии метки не может быть пробела. Как в имени переменной в большинстве языков. В абсолютном большинстве случаев его заменяет дефис: [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Если вы пытаетесь ввести метку через дефис, а такой метки нет - значит и не надо, хватит тех, что уже добавили.

---

**дополнение: таблицы добавили году в 2021 кажется*

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |